# Syntax for an if statement referrering to a value in a control

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I would like to know the correct way to refer to the value in a current record on a form to automatically change the format of a control on the form depending on the value of the record.  For example, if i have a form named frmProject and within that form I have a control named txtPriority which shows the field "priority" from a table, what is the correct syntax to make it so that the control txtPriority changes to the colour RED if the priority is listed as "HIGH"?
(i know there is a conditional format function in MS Access, but i am Learning VBA and would prefer to understand how to write a sub routine)
Thanks,
A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within a form's code module, you can refer to that form's controls simply by its name. If no property is specified after the control name, the default property (Value) is referenced.

```
Sub ControlColors()
  Select Case txtPriority
    Case "HIGH":
      txtPriority.BackColor = vbRed
    Case Else:
      txtPriority.BackColor = vbWhite
  End Select 
End Sub
```

You would then add a call to `ControlColors` inside the form's On_Current event (to update after each record navigation) and also in the txtPriority After_Update event (to reflect the change on a current record).

I'd use a Select Case instead of If because you are likely to check for multiple conditions. Note that this type of highlighting will not work for a continuous form -- conditional formatting is required for that to work.

Comment: Fantastic. Thanks. I thought that there was a way to do with code what "conditional formatting" does but i guess I was wrong.